# Which executables I can delete in the "bin" directory of MySQL for a lightweight distribution

Tags: windows, mysql, portable

I need to create a **very lightweight** distribution of MySQL for Windows.

I've already downloaded a portable (no install) version, I removed some non vital directories (like `mysql-test` and similar), and I changed `my.ini` properly. It works fine, including InnoDB.

The problem is that it sill takes 147 MB. I've seen the most is inside the `bin` directory, where there is a bunch of executables, taking about 3-8 MB each. Can I safely delete some of them? Which of them?

Thank you in advance.

P.S.: no, I cannot migrate to sqlite, I have to stick with MySQL. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [MicroSQL](http://microapache.kerys.co.uk/)

MicroSQL is a standalone package that is shipped as an option to MicroApache. From the website

**Deleteable Components**

> If you use an external web-based manager such as PHPMyAdmin and never
>   use the CMD-line admin or access functions then you can reduce the
>   footprint by deleting mysql.exe and mysqladmin.exe (and mysqlwatch.exe
>   + mysqlcheck.exe if supplied) Note that you need msqladmin.exe to use
>   the stop/start batch files to control the MySQL console service.

**Removed Components**

```
13/01/2005 08:46   122,880 my_print_defaults.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,093,632 myisam_ftdump.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,200,128 myisamchk.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,118,208 myisamlog.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,118,208 myisampack.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,064,960 mysqlbinlog.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,044,480 mysqlcheck.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 3,493,888 mysqld.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,064,960 mysqldump.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,044,480 mysqlimport.exe
07/01/2005 00:30 1,523,200 MySQLInstanceConfig.exe
13/01/2005 08:46 1,040,384 mysqlshow.exe
13/01/2005 08:46    40,960 mysqlshutdown.exe
13/01/2005 08:46    45,056 mysqlwatch.exe
13/01/2005 08:46   110,592 perror.exe
```

The size of the package is **2.9mb**.

[Download MicroSQL 4.1.9-3 (2.9 Mb ZIP file)](http://microapache.kerys.co.uk/bin/microsql/Micro-SQL-4.1.9-3.zip)   (Apache/PHP binaries/modules are NOT included)